# How to display every week in TortoiseSVN statistics, including weeks with zero commits?

Tags: tortoise-svn

When displaying commits by date statistics in ToroiseSVN, the weeks or months with zero commits are automatically hidden. In other words, if there were:

- 9 commits for week 19,
- 4 commits for week 20,
- 0 commits for week 21 and
- 1 commit for week 22,

only three weeks will be displayed.

[image]

I know this is by design and allows to visualize better the projects which were abandoned for a long time. But sometimes, it may be misleading and I want to see all the weeks, including those with zero commits, to be able to visually identify specifically the periods of time where the project was inactive.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something more complex. Like [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/).

I haven't used it myself, but I wouldn't expect more to come from TortoiseSVN than what you're already seeing.

Most of their demos seem to be broken right now, but the one for [Continuum](http://statsvn.org/demo/continuum/) works.

[image]